# Установить атрибут selected в выпадающем списке

Tags: vue.js

При использовании директивы `v-if` пункты в выпадающем списке не выводятся:

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" v-model="form.gender" :value="form.gender.value">
  <option value="0">Не указано</option>
  <option value="1" v-if="form.gender === 1" selected>Мужской</option>
  <option value="2" v-if="form.gender === 2" selected>Женский</option>
</select>
```

Как установить выбранный пункт в зависимости от заданного значения переменной (то есть свойства `form.gender`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы несколько переусердствовали с выводом значения. Vue сам выставит нужное значение в выпадающем списке при изменении значения `form.gender`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {
      gender: 1
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    submitHandler(event) {}
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="submitHandler">

    <label><input type="radio" v-model="form.gender" value=""> Не указано</label>
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="form.gender" value="1"> Мужской</label>
    <label><input type="radio" v-model="form.gender" value="2"> Женский</label>

    <hr />

    <select v-model="form.gender">
      <option value="">Не указано</option>
      <option value="1">Мужской</option>
      <option value="2">Женский</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <pre v-if="form.gender">Сейчас выбрано: {{ form.gender }}</pre>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```